# CommandButton's action URL depending on the form content

Tags: forms, jsf, redirect, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm doing a simple search engine for my web app and I'm facing a problem.

My `search.xhtml` works by getting a parameter, so that `search.xhtml?key=lol` will return the results for "lol".

What I need to do is that my search commandButton will redirect do `search.xhtml?key=INPUT TEXT CONTENT`.

Here's my simple code :

```
<div id="searchBox">
        <pou:panel id="searchPanel">                
            <h:form>
                <h:inputText id="searchInput" value="#{dispensaRicercaBean.query}" size="99" maxlength="99"/> <pou:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" action="ricerca?faces-redirect=true"/>
                <pou:watermark value="Search" for="searchInput"/>
            </h:form>                
        </pou:panel>            
    </div>
```

where `dispensaRicercaBean` is `@RequestScoped` and my result page loads the data calling `executeQuery(#{request.getParameter('key'))` (a rough example, actually there are some differences)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a plain HTML `<form>`

```
<form action="ricera.xhtml">
    <h:inputText id="key" size="99" maxlength="99" />
    <pou:watermark value="Search" for="key" />
    <pou:button icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="submit(); return;" />
</form>
```